# Grub 1.99 default?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, startup, bios

I have been running into an issue.  I have my grub set to run the only OS on power on, and the BIOS to automatically restart the machine if it dies.  The issue is that if the machine dies (from say a power failure), when it is powered back on it still gets stuck on the GRUB loading screen.  Is there any way to skip this screen no matter what and boot into the OS (in this case ubuntu)?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather a bug and the solution is already given at

[how to force grub to boot (no human input) regardless previous booting failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/269387/how-to-force-grub-to-boot-no-human-input-regardless-previous-booting-failure)

**bug:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/841009

Comment: np,have a nice day!